# A conversão de um tipo de dados nvarchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo

Tags: sql-server, query, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Linha de código

```
INSERT [dbo].[Shop_Goods] ([TemplateID], [Name], [Remark], [CategoryID], [Description],
[Attack], [Defence], [Agility], [Luck], [Level], [Quality], [Pic], [MaxCount], [NeedSex],
[NeedLevel], [CanStrengthen], [CanCompose], [CanDrop], [CanEquip], [CanUse], [CanDelete],
[Script], [Data], [Colors], [Property1], [Property2], [Property3], [Property4], 
[Property5], [Property6], [Property7], [Property8], [Valid], [Count], [AddTime], 
[BindType], [FusionType], [FusionRate], [FusionNeedRate], [Hole], [RefineryLevel], 
[ReclaimValue], [ReclaimType], [CanRecycle], [FloorPrice], [SuitId], [CanTransfer],
[Price])
VALUES (4427, N'Ágata Roxa', N'null', 4, N'', 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, N'eff127', 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, N'', N'', N'', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0,
CAST(N'2016-02-23 06:20:24.000' AS DateTime),2, 0, 0, 0, N'0,-1|0,-1|0,-1|0,-1|0,-1|0,-1',
 -1, 10, 1, 1, 100, 0, 1, NULL)
```

> Mensagem 242, Nível 16, Estado 3, Linha 1922 A conversão de um tipo de
>   dados nvarchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora
>   do intervalo.

Queria saber o porque do erro, estou executando uma query de quase 10 mil linhas e várias deu este erro.

Comment: Seu erro já diz tudo, você tem um insert que esta com a data errada. `CAST(N'2016-02-23 06:20:24.000' AS DateTime)`, de onde esta vindo essas suas 1000 ? é um select?

Comment: Ou tente usar o convert(varchar,CAST,103).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tente usar o [DATEFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) , para setar o formato da data.

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;  
SELECT CAST(N'2016-02-23 06:20:24.000' AS DateTime)
```

Na sua query ficaria assim;

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd; 
INSERT [dbo].[Shop_Goods] ([TemplateID], [Name], [Remark], [CategoryID], [Description],
[Attack], [Defence], [Agility], [Luck], [Level], [Quality], [Pic], [MaxCount], [NeedSex],
[NeedLevel], [CanStrengthen], [CanCompose], [CanDrop], [CanEquip], [CanUse], [CanDelete],
[Script], [Data], [Colors], [Property1], [Property2], [Property3], [Property4], 
[Property5], [Property6], [Property7], [Property8], [Valid], [Count], [AddTime], 
[BindType], [FusionType], [FusionRate], [FusionNeedRate], [Hole], [RefineryLevel], 
[ReclaimValue], [ReclaimType], [CanRecycle], [FloorPrice], [SuitId], [CanTransfer],
[Price])
VALUES (4427, N'Ágata Roxa', N'null', 4, N'', 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, N'eff127', 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, N'', N'', N'', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0,
CAST(N'2016-02-23 06:20:24.000' AS DateTime),2, 0, 0, 0, N'0,-1|0,-1|0,-1|0,-1|0,-1|0,-1',
 -1, 10, 1, 1, 100, 0, 1, NULL)
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo funcionou :)

Answer (score 4):

Tive um problema parecido, mas com `SELECT CAST(N'2016-02-23 06:20:24.000' AS DateTime)` não funcionou.

Testei também `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2016-02-23 06:20:24.000')` e não funcionou.

Mas, passando o formato 121, deu certo: `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2016-02-23 06:20:24.000', 121)`