# Ajuda com SqlQuery em contexto Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

Preciso fazer um retorno do meu banco de dados de uma maneira específica, porém estou com um problema, a situação é a seguinte:

Tenho essa *query* já testada diretamente no *SQL Server*, e está funcionando perfeitamente:

```
SELECT
    COUNT (ate.id) AS data,
    pes.tp_raca AS categories,
    pes.genero AS name
FROM
    Atendimento ate
INNER JOIN Pessoa pes ON pes.id = ate.pessoa_id
WHERE
    ate.dt_atendimento >= '2018-08-20'
AND ate.dt_atendimento <= '2018-11-10'
GROUP BY
    pes.tp_raca,
    pes.genero
```

E retorna o seguinte resultado:

```
data categories  name
 1        5      Feminino
 1        2      Masculino
 2        5      Masculino
```

No código *C#*, a query ficou assim:

```
using (var context = new SiviasContext())
{
   DateTime inicio = new DateTime(2018,08,20);
   DateTime fim = new DateTime(2018,11,10);
   var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<List<Tuple<int, string, string>>>("SELECT COUNT (ate.id) AS data, pes.tp_raca AS categories, " +
    "pes.genero AS name FROM Atendimento ate INNER JOIN Pessoa pes ON pes.id = ate.pessoa_id " +
    "WHERE ate.dt_atendimento >= "+inicio.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+" AND ate.dt_atendimento <= "+ fim.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +
    " GROUP BY pes.tp_raca, pes.genero").ToList();
   ViewBag.result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

Do jeito que está, não apresenta erro, mas ele retorna uma lista vazia. Repare que a execução direta no *SQL* uso a data como string, mas se eu usar como string no código *C#*, ele apresenta um erro dizendo que não é possível usar uma string em um tipo DateTime. Ou seja, ele reconhece que o atributo de data no banco de dados é do tipo Datetime.

Já tentei usar a data sem passar o **.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")** para formatar, porém ele também apresenta um erro reclamando dos **00 *(zeros)*** do time contido na data.

Então, gostaria que pudessem me ajudar nisso, como resolvo?

==============================================================

A resolução foi dada seguindo a ideia do @Pedro Paulo, ficando assim:

```
List<RetornoConsulta> result = context.Atendimentos.Where(x => x.dt_atendimento >= dt_inicio)
                            .Where(x => x.dt_atendimento <= dt_fim)
                            .Select(g => new {
                                categories = g.Pessoa.tp_raca.ToString(),
                                name = g.Pessoa.genero
                            })
                            .GroupBy(g => new {
                                categories = g.categories,
                                name = g.name
                            })
                            .Select(g => new RetornoConsulta
                             {
                                 data = g.Count(),
                                 categories = g.Key.categories.ToString(),
                                 name = g.Key.name
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Por que voce não usa Linq? Suas models não estão mapeadas? Com linq a busca é mais simples e é mais facil de se usar

Comment: Eu gostaria mas não consegui pelo seguinte: Aqui estou apresentando um exemplo de query já pronta. Pois preciso montar uma query que receba filtros como parâmetros opcionais e também cruzar duas informações utilizando o _group by_, mas não consegui utilizar ele no _IQueryAble_. Funcionaria assim, o usuário escolhe os dois campos a serem cruzados. No retorno verifico qual o primeiro campo a ser cruzado e faço o _group by_ em cima dele, depois o segundo a ser cruzado e faço outro _group by_ dele em cima do anterior, mas tive dificuldade nisso, por isso optei por fazer digitando a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro crie uma classe que represente o retorno dos dados da sua consulta:

```
public class RetornoConsulta
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
    public string Categories { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Na sua consulta iremos passar as datas de início e fim como parâmetros para a query com a classe `SQLParameter` do Entity Framework, e informaremos que o retorno será uma lista de objetos da nossa classe `RetornoConsulta`:

```
List<SqlParameter> parametros = new List<SqlParameter> 
{
    new SqlParameter("@dataInicio", inicio),
    new SqlParameter("@dataFim", fim)
};

var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<RetornoConsulta>(
                 @"SELECT COUNT (ate.id) AS Data, 
                     pes.tp_raca AS Categories, 
                     pes.genero AS Name
                   FROM Atendimento ate 
                   INNER JOIN Pessoa pes 
                    ON pes.id = ate.pessoa_id
                   WHERE ate.dt_atendimento BETWEEN @dataInicio AND @dataFim
                   GROUP BY pes.tp_raca, pes.genero", 
                   parametros.ToArray()
                ).ToList();
```

Comment: Consegui executar, ele não retornou erro, e retornou uma lista na quantidade que eu esperava, porém vieram vazias: **result: [[],[],[]]**

Comment: Como eu faço pra ele retornar o resultado já reconhecendo a classe?

Comment: Tente alterar da forma que está agora, removendo o `List<RetornoConsulta>` do `SqlQuery` e adicionando o `ToList<RetornoConsulta>()`.

Comment: Não dá certo, o próprio Visual Studio reclama: **Nõ é possível converter de 'string' para 'System.Type'**

Comment: Tente novamente da forma editada.

Comment: Retorna: **Não existe mapeamento do tipo de objeto System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] para um provedor gerenciado de tipo nativo.**

Comment: Tente passar os parâmetros `SqlParameter` individualmente, ao invés de uma lista, veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149978/8133067), ou use `parametros.ToArray()` ao invés da lista, como sugerido [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916146/8133067). Ou faça uma solução mesclada, escreva a query como eu sugeri, sem parâmetros, mas use a classe `RetornoConsulta` que o Pedro Paulo sugeriu, no lugar do `Tuple<int, string, string>`.

Comment: Segui a sua ideia e consegui resolver o que precisava, porém utilizando o LinQ. Irei editar minha pergunta para demonstrar como ficou a solução

Comment: @PedroPaulo, depois seria interessante editar sua resposta modificando a passagem da lista `parametros` como argumento do método `SqlQuery()`, porque assim dá erro. Teria que passar cada argumento individualmente ou transformar a lista em array, como sugeri aí em cima.

Comment: Feito, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A query do SQL Server funciona porque lá você está delimitando os valores do campo data entre aspas simples (`'`):

```
WHERE
    ate.dt_atendimento >= '2018-08-20'
AND ate.dt_atendimento <= '2018-11-10'
```

Mas no C# não está.

Faça assim:

```
var dtIni = inicio.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var dtFim = fim.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<List<Tuple<int, string, string>>>(
      "SELECT COUNT(ate.id) AS data, pes.tp_raca AS categories, pes.genero AS name" +
      " FROM Atendimento ate INNER JOIN Pessoa pes ON pes.id = ate.pessoa_id" +
     $" WHERE ate.dt_atendimento BETWEEN '{dtIni}' AND '{dtFim}'" +
      " GROUP BY pes.tp_raca, pes.genero"
   ).ToList();
```

Usei [interpolação de strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) (exemplo: `$"'{var}'"`, disponível a partir do C# 6.0, Visual Studio 2015) para o código ficar mas legível:

```
     $" WHERE ate.dt_atendimento BETWEEN '{dtIni}' AND '{dtFim}'" +
```

Caso você esteja usando uma versão anterior do C#/Visual Studio, você pode trocar essa linha do filtro para usar `String.Format()`:

```
      String.Format(" WHERE ate.dt_atendimento BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}'", dtIni, dtFim) +
```

Ou usar a concatenação de `strings` simplesmente, como estava fazendo antes:

```
      " WHERE ate.dt_atendimento BETWEEN '" + dtIni + "' AND '" + dtFim + "'" +
```

**EDIÇÃO**

Ainda assim o autor da pergunta relatou que ocorria o erro:

> A conversão de um tipo de dados nvarchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.
>   (*The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*)

Nesse caso o formato de data configurado para a base no SQL Server pode estar diferente de `ymd`. Para verificar qual formato está configurado para a base, execute a consulta:

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

E verifique o registro cuja coluna `Set Option` seja `dateformat`.

Para forçar um formato nessa consulta, individualmente, use o comando `SET DATEFORMAT ymd` ([docmentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) e [referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141970/86952)):

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<List<Tuple<int, string, string>>>(
      "SET DATEFORMAT ymd; " +
      "SELECT COUNT(ate.id) AS data, pes.tp_raca AS categories, pes.genero AS name" +
      " FROM Atendimento ate INNER JOIN Pessoa pes ON pes.id = ate.pessoa_id" +
     $" WHERE ate.dt_atendimento BETWEEN '{dtIni}' AND '{dtFim}'" +
      " GROUP BY pes.tp_raca, pes.genero"
   ).ToList();
```

Comment: Olá Pedro, no caso, fiz aqui o teste, mas ele deu na mesma, ele retornou o erro _A conversão de um tipo de dados varchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo_.

Comment: Estranho, não faz muito sentido. Faz de novo como o Marcelo Macedo tinha sugerido, coloca um breakpoint ai nessa linha em que você monta a query, seleciona todo o texto da consulta e verifica qual foi o texto que ele gerou, depois pega esse mesmo texto e cola numa query no SQL Server Management Studio e roda, para ver se dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Muito estranho mesmo. Executei no SQL Server, ele retornou _A conversão de um tipo de dados varchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo_. Se eu tiro as aspas, ele não dá erro mas também não retorna resultado

Comment: Aspas simples (`'`) ou aspas duplas (`"`)? Mas você não tinha dito que aquela consulta da pergunta, com aspas simples (`'`) estava funcionando no SQL Server? A forma normal de representar datas no SQL Server é usando as aspas simples, veja [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql).

Comment: Quando você faz uma consulta no SQL Server Management Studio, em que formato ele exibe as datas? Veja o comando [SET DATEFORMAT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) e essa resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141970/86952).

Comment: Entendi, então, eu verifiquei aqui, eu estava utilizando o _Navicat Premium_ para executar as querys, estava funcionando nele, mas quando executei no _SQL Server_ apresentou o erro de conversão da data

Comment: E como as datas são exibidas quando você visualiza os registros no SQL Server Management?

Comment: Retornei um _select * from_ e mostra assim: **2018-11-08 10:36:27.710**

Comment: Tenta fazer a consulta assim: `SET DATEFORMAT ymd; SELECT ...` para ver se dá certo.

Comment: Deu certo no SQL Server, e como faria no sistema então?

Comment: Consegui executar colocando o **SET DATEFORMAT ymd;** antes do **SELECT**, ele não retornou erro, e retornou uma lista na quantidade que eu esperava, porém vieram vazias: result: [[],[],[]]

Comment: @TácioBrito, ao invés de fazer `context.Database.SqlQuery<List<Tuple<int, string, string>>>("SELECT ...").ToList();`, tenta fazer assim: `context.Database.SqlQuery("SELECT ...").ToList<Tuple<int, string, string>>();`.

Comment: @TácioBrito, eu estava fazendo uma pesquisa e parece que o `context.Database.SqlQuery()` não pode ser usado mesmo em tipos "anônimos", como `Tuple`. Talvez você tenha que fazer uma solução como a que o Pedro Paulo sugeriu mesmo, criando uma classe específica com os campos que serão retornados na consulta.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar between. Ficando assim:

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<List<Tuple<int, string, string>>>("SELECT COUNT (ate.id) AS data, pes.tp_raca AS categories, " +
    "pes.genero AS name FROM Atendimento ate INNER JOIN Pessoa pes ON pes.id = ate.pessoa_id " +
    "WHERE ate.dt_atendimento between "+inicio.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+" AND "+ fim.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +
    " GROUP BY pes.tp_raca, pes.genero").ToList();
   ViewBag.result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Comment: O Between deu na mesma, é o mesmo resultado

Comment: Já tentou "dd/MM/yyyy" ?

Comment: Também não, sem a condição WHERE da data ele retorna, mas com ela não ta funcionando

Comment: Cara põe um breakpoint na variável result e passa o mouse pra ver o que ta indo pra ela de string. Pode ser que tenha que pôr duas aspas duplas antes e duas depois das strings internas, ficando assim: ""yyyy-MM-dd"" .

Comment: Outra coisa que eu vi aqui @TácioBrito é que data e name são palavras reservadas do SQL, tenta por outras palavras no lugar.

Comment: A query retorna assim: SELECT COUNT (ate.id) AS data, pes.tp_raca AS categories, pes.genero AS name FROM Atendimento ate INNER JOIN Pessoa pes ON pes.id = ate.pessoa_id WHERE ate.dt_atendimento BETWEEN 2018-08-20 AND 2018-11-10 GROUP BY pes.tp_raca, pes.genero

a data vem sem aspa, mas se eu colocar aspa ele reclama dizendo que é sttring, ocorrendo incompatibilidade com o tipo DateTime. Mas no SQL direto funciona

Comment: Tenta aquela outra formatação de data. "dd/MM/yyyy". E testa esse lance de aspas duplas também.

Comment: Já testei todos essas sugestões que me passou, é emitido Exception em ambas

Comment: Até a questão das palavras reservadas que te falei acima?

Comment: Outra coisa que eu vi aqui @TácioBrito é que data e name são palavras reservadas do SQL, tenta por outras palavras no lugar. – Marcelo Macedo 13 mins atrás

Comment: Sim coloquei outras: COUNT (ate.id) AS qtd, pes.tp_raca AS categorias, "pes.genero AS nome

nada ta pegando, não to entendendo. Assim, poderia usar outra maneira pra essa query, por exemplo o CodeFirst, mas eu preciso fazer group by de campos dinamicamente, conforme o usuário seleciona, pra cruzar dados, mas nao consegui retornar pelo IQueryAble

Comment: Cara, posso ta enganado. Sua query tem duas colunas e ta passando pra uma list. A List não suportaria 1 só coluna? Tira uma coluna pra testar.

Comment: Me retornou um array de array vazio, assim: [[]]